# Attempting a more-than if statement causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'm very new to iOS development, and I may seem like an idiot asking this.
But trying this action makes the app crash entirely.

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender
{
    if(NSInteger >= 4) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                 target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        NSLog(@"Action: ‘action' succeeded");
    }
    else
    {
        [screen setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“You cannot do this."]];
        NSLog(@"Action: ‘action' failed");
    }
}
```

Countup is defined as:

```
- (void)countup
{
    NSInteger += 1;
    [screen setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seconds: %d", NSInteger]];
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I've tried to fix it for hours and I can't find any answers that help me.

Comment: `NSInteger >= 4` & `NSInteger += 1`: `NSInteger`, that's the variable name?

Comment: They're the same value

Comment: I think this code didn't run at all.

Comment: @StevenM `NSInteger += 1` should be `NSInteger myInt +=1` and you should follow that all over the app `NSInteger` is the type `myInt` is your actual variable that you can manipulate.

Comment: @sbarow: If that were the reason than the app would not *compile*. But OP claims that it *crashes*. - (Btw, you *can* call a variable `NSInteger`, that does not mean that you *should!*)

Comment: @MartinR I think the claim of a crash and a compile might be confused by the OP. But agree with you on the NSInteger variable naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you have at least some knowledge of computer programming in some other language then Objective-C.

I will talk about this line, but the same problem occurs in several lines in your code

```
if(NSInteger >= 4)
```

You compare the type NSInteger with a number (4). I assume you want to compare a variable of the type NSInteger with the number 4!

Therefore your code would look something like this:

```
NSInteger mySavedNumber = 20;
if(mySavedNumber >= 4)
```

Ofc. 'mySavedNumber' is a name of the variable that I chose randomly and you should probably change it for something that makes sense for you, but I don't know the rest of your code, I can't really tell what you wanted to do. But you can't name it NSInteger, since 'NSInteger' is a name that is already taken.

For the same reason I was talking about, this line of code also wont work:

```
NSInteger += 1;
```

Again, NSInteger is just a type and not a variable itself.

Comment: If that were the reason than the app would not *compile*. But OP claims that it *crashes*. - (Btw, you *can* call a variable `NSInteger`, that does not mean that you *should!*)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a variable.

```
NSInteger x;
```

and then

```
if (x >= 4) ...
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seconds: %d", x] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude you need to create a variable of type NSInteger. create a variable and then use it instead of NSInteger.

Change code to

```
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger num;

    if(num >= 4) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        NSLog(@"Action: ‘action' succeeded");
    }
    else {
        [screen setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“You cannot do this."]];

        NSLog(@"Action: ‘action' failed");
    }
}

-(void)countup
{
    num += 1;
    [screen setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seconds: %d", num]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSInteger` is a type not a variable.
You should have `NSInteger myInt` and the using `myInt`

```
if(myInt >= 4)
```

and

```
myInt++;
```